# ¿Por qué al hacer un INSERT INTO crea varios registros?

Tags: php, mysql

He creado un modelo de base de datos como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla 'Inscripcion' integra los datos de 'Alumno' y 'Asignatura' ya que esta dos ultimas tienen relacion N:N

Además estoy desarrollando un sistema de control de usuarios.
Lo que ocurre que cuando deseo crear una INSCRIPCION de alumno a una asignatura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se ejecuta el codigo del INSERT INTO:

```
<?php

  include('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CRUD_UPLA/core/models/coneccion.php');

  if($_GET['alumno']) {
      $alumno = $_GET['alumno'];
      $asignatura = $_GET['asignatura'];
      $periodo = $_GET['periodo'];
      $oportunidad = $_GET['oportunidad'];

      $consulta = "INSERT INTO Inscripcion (rut, cod_asign, periodo, oportunidad, estado)
                   VALUES ('$alumno', '$asignatura', '$periodo' ,'$oportunidad', 'ins')";

      if($conexion->query($consulta)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Bien Hecho!</strong> Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoreamente.</a>
              </div>';
            header('Location: http://localhost/CRUD_UPLA/index.php?view=inscripcion_alumno');


      } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>ERROR!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">No se pudieron actualizar</a> los datos.
              </div>';

      }
}
?>

coneccion.php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$pass = '';
$bd = 'Concentracion';

$conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bd);

if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
  echo "ERROR AL CONECTARSE {$conexion->connect_errno}";
}

$link = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass)
    or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
//echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db($bd) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
```

Esta sentencia crea multiples registros de inscripcion en la base de datos, cuando en realidad solo deberia crear SOLO UNO. ¿se entiende?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo normal seria que cuando hago una inscripcion me cree SOLO UN REGISTRO en la tabla de la base de datos, no SEIS como este caso.

Solo cuando inserto los datos manualmente por base de datos me crea un registro.

Es posible solucionar esto?, porque le he dado muchas vueltas a esto pero no encuentro sentido.

El boton Inscribir del "formulario" esta definido de la siguiente manera:

```
<a class="inscribir_alumno btn btn-primary">Inscribir</a>
```

Y este es el metodo en javascript, utilizando ajax

```
  $(function() {
    $("a.inscribir_alumno").click(function() {
      var alumno = document.getElementById('inputAlumno_ins').value;
      var asignatura = document.getElementById('inputAsignatura_ins').value;
      var periodo = document.getElementById('inputPeriodo_ins').value;
      var oportunidad = document.getElementById('inputOportunidad_ins').value;
      var dataString = 'alumno=' + alumno + '&asignatura=' + asignatura + '&periodo=' + periodo + '&oportunidad=' + oportunidad;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/CRUD_UPLA/core/bin/ajax/inscribir_alumno.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
          window.location.href = "http://localhost/CRUD_UPLA/core/bin/ajax/inscribir_alumno.php?alumno=" + alumno + '&asignatura=' + asignatura + '&periodo=' + periodo + '&oportunidad=' + oportunidad;
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Por favor no pongas imágenes del código fuente. En su lugar, coloca aquí el código relevante para entender y reproducir tu problema. Te recomiendo revisar [mcve]

Comment: ¿Qué tiene el archivo coneccion.php? ¿Tienes ciclos en alguna parte del código?

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué ejecutas el `INSERT` en una petición GET? Usualmente GET se usa para consultar información, como cuando accedes a la página por el navegador, lo que significa que cada vez que el usuario ingrese a esta página (ni siquiera seleccionar alguna opción) se va a ejecutar un `INSERT`. Sería mejor cambiar el proceso a que se realice en un POST (procesamiento de información).

Comment: El problema es como envias los datos, escribe las lineas

Comment: Y la definicion de tu formulario???, intenta cambiar de Get a Request

Comment: No uso formulario utilizo peticiones con ajax

Comment: Muestralas.......

Comment: Agregué mas informacion a la pregunta

Comment: El problema es que lo estas redirigiendo a la misma pagina... ósea estás enviando 2 veces lo mismo... y las otras 4... apuesto que haz refrescado la pagina 4 veces...

Comment: entiendo. CAMBIE EL REDIRECCIONAMIENTO A OTRA PAGINA ahora en vez de 6 registros me crea 3. debe ser que cada vez que ejecuta el insert crea esos 3 registros

Comment: En tu ajax estas usando el metodo get para obtener la información del formulario, y como success estas colocando que redireccione a la pagina y mandas por la url la información que enviaste en una primera instancia. Trata de hacerlo sin redireccionar para ver que sucede, como usas Ajax no se cual es el sentido de redireccionar a la misma url

Comment: Si a alguien le sirve, yo tambien tube el problema y era por que estaba utilizando un actualizador que refrescaba la pagina, lo desabilite y de ahí todo normal.

Answer (score 0):

Tu formulario

```
<form action="" name="form_insert_asignatura" onsubmit="insert_asignatura(); return false" >
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Alumno</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alumno" id="alumno" placeholder="Nombre del Alumno">
    </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Asignatura</label>
            <select name="asignatura" id="asignatura" required="required" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
            <?php
            $select="SELECT * FROM asignaturas";
            $rec=mysqli_query($cn,$select);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rec)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['asignatura'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
      <input type="submit"  name="Submit" class="pull-right btn btn-default" value="Guardar">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Tu Codigo Ajax

```
             function objetoAjax(){
                var xmlhttp=false;
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {

                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
            if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
                  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                return xmlhttp;
            }

        function insert_asignatura(){
              divasignaturas = document.getElementById('divasignaturas');
              alumno=document.form_insert_asignatura.alumno.value;
              asignatura=document.form_insert_asignatura.asignatura.value;
              ajax=objetoAjax();
              ajax.open("POST", "insert_asignatura.php",true);
              ajax.onreadystatechange=function() 
              {
                    if (ajax.readyState==4) 
                    {
                        divasignaturas.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
                        LimpiarCampos();
                        swal("Dato Agregado", "Correcto", "success")
                    }
             }
                ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajax.send("alumno="+alumno+"&asignatura="+asignatura)

        }
```

Como Recibes los Parametros

```
            <?php
            include("../php/conexion.php");
            $alumno=$_POST['alumno'];
            $asignatura=$_POST['asignatura'];
            $orden=mysqli_query($cn,"insert into asignaturas (alumno,asignatura) values ('$alumno','$asignatura')");
            include('select_asignaturas.php');
            ?>
```

Comment: @Carlo Echeverria Si consideras que te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema favor de marcarla como validad